# Extract more rows from a left join with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have to extract the rows where the **created_at** is inside the week. Unfortunately, only one line is extracted from me and no more lines as I expected. Why?

**Query:**

```
 $scadenze = DB::table('processi')
 ->leftJoin('scadenze', 'processi.id', '=', 'scadenze.processo_id')
 ->where('responsabile',$utente->id)
 ->whereNotIn('scadenze.stato', [4,5])
 ->whereBetween('scadenze.termine_stimato',[\Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])
 ->avg('tempistica');
```

[image]

This query extract just one row, but in reality many more lines should be extracted.

Comment: [avg](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) is an aggregate operation. so you get just the avg result.

Answer (score 1):

Because `->avg('tempistica');` return average value from all your rows in this query, i.e. return just one value.

Comment: This query extract just one row, but in reality many more lines should be extracted.

Comment: With `->avg('tempistica');` you say to the script: "get all values based on the query above and show me average value of all `tempistica` items.". Try to replace `->avg('tempistica');`  with `->get()`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
I was wrong to use the **avg** with **sum** function. The rows were extracted correctly but instead of being added (by timing) an average was made. Thank you all for your help.